# Firebase createUser() does not create user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to play around with Firebase, I have this piece of code but the user is not getting created.

I've enabled email and password auth on Firebase. The Firebase url is correct.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Button BCreate;
        BCreate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Createbutton);
        BCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e("URL", "Before firebase url");

                go();
            }
        });
    }

    private void go() {
        final Firebase ref=new Firebase("https://testingbasee.firebaseio.com");
        Log.e("GOOOOOO!", "gooooooo!");

       ref.createUser("aa@bb.com", "12345", new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess() {
               Log.e("GOOOOOO!","gooooooo!");
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
               Log.e("NOPOOOOOOOO!","noooo!!1!");
           }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which log lines do you get in logcat? Did you step through the code? If there is an error: what is the `firebaseError`?

Comment: Log.e("URL", "Before firebase url");
 Log.e("GOOOOOO!", "gooooooo!");
Log.e("NOPOOOOOOOO!","noooo!!1!");
These are the Log lines, I am not sure as to what is wrong here?

Comment: Hey, I got it. The emulator on which I was running my app was not able to access the internet hence it was spitting out this error.

Comment: Just saying, but I recommend you update to the latest version of Firebase which can be found at firebase.google.com. It's totally up to you, but the newer one has more features...